# how to show <a> on div ( parent mouse over) with live function?

Tags: jquery

I  have one div , inside div i have one `<a>` , i want to show `<a>` on mouse over on div

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <img width="40" height="40" style="cursor:pointer" title="fwe" alt="image" src="../Images/DefaultPhotoMale.png" id="img513a06fa7f6d160310e09ac9">
    <a style="position: absolute;display:none; top: 1px; margin-left: 50px;">X</a>
    </div>
```

i did this, but i dont get correct result, i am able to see next div  on other, any other options please

```
$("#mycarousel").find("div").live({
        mouseenter:
           function () {
               $(this).find('a').show();
           },
        mouseleave:
           function () {
               $(this).find('a').hide();
           }
    }
    );
```

Comment: .live() has been **depreciated** as of jQuery 1.7 - http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished **without JavaScript**, using *pure* CSS.

```
div a {
    display: none;
}

div:hover a {
   display: block;
}
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/TjVkS/

Answer (score 2):

As of jQuery 1.7, [the `live()` method is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Use `on()` instead. It works quite well for me like this:

<kbd>[**Working demo**](http://jsbin.com/iwevam/3/edit)</kbd>

Comment: Yes, but i see same problem what i faced, try to fresh a page and do mouse over and mouse move, you can see that image place is different!

Comment: As for the position, I cleaned up a bit your markup by separating the style in css, and everything is fixed as, I think, you wanted it to be.

Comment: As for that error, it baffles me unless you got rid of jQuery in the head of the JSBin. In any case, try out the new link.